# creating db triggers in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual Stuiod 2008 and MS SQL. I have created all tables/procedures and functions from server explorer of VS.

How do I create triggers? For example if a row is deleted/modified then do certain things.

Thanks
Behrouz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Managment Studio is a good tool.

I just found my answer, in VS 2008, click on the Table, then from the Menu click on Data->Add New

Comment: You can add triggers like this (vs2013) YourDatabase->Tables->YourTable->Click on the arrow (left side) of your table -> right click on trigger--> Add new Trigger.... Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember if it's all the same in VS 2008, but in 2010, you have special project type (Database -> SQL Server ) and there you can add to your project all kinds of database stuff including triggers. After that it creates a DDL file to create your database.

On the other hand you can define and extend your triggers using SQL Managment Studio, it's a common tool based on VS shell so it's easy to learn. (Databases->YourDb->Tables->YourTable->Triggers->New Trigger)